# Fill percentage area of an arbitrary SVG path

Tags: svg, d3.js, raphael

Given an arbitrary SVG path, such as a country, how can I best fill a percentage of its inner area? Filling the bounding box will be inaccurate for anything that isn't a rectangle.

Any advice greatly appreciated - I can use any tech. Either generating the SVGs on a server or doing it with canvas or D3 or Raphael.

Thanks

(PS I have read some other questions but the answer didn't really help).

Comment: Use a [gradient with transparency](http://www.mathachew.com/blog/css-svg-gradients-with-transparency/).

Comment: This is really a complicated mathematical question, rather than a coding question.  However, you could start with [d3's polygon methods](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Polygon-Geom) which allow you to calculate the area of arbitrary polygons, and to clip one polygon (e.g., your country outline) to another (e.g., a rectangle) to create a new polygon that you could calculate the area of.  From there, you could use a numerical approximation approach until the clipped region has the correct area.  (If you really need arbitrary paths, including curves, it would get much more complicated...)